# How do you skip deleting a file after you get an error?

Tags: python, file-io, operating-system, delete-file

I need to make the process that deletes all files in the temp folder when I run the program it says
"The process can not access the file because it is being used by another process.", so I tried to make it skip the file if it said that but it doesn't work. I am also very new to python.
Here is my code:

```py
if event in ('Delete Temp'):
    while ("temp"):
        os.system('cmd /c "del /q/f/s %TEMP%\*"')

        if print('The process can not access the file because it is being used by another process.')
            pass
```

Comment: The `if print` part of your code is an incorrect way of using print, what you're looking for, is `exception handling`, have a look at this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-set-5-exception-handling/)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your delete command within `try/except` block and instead of `os` module use `subprocess` in order to throw an exception in case of failure:

```
from subprocess import run
while condition:
    try:
        run('cmd /c "del /q/f/s %TEMP%\*"', shell=True, check=True)
    except CalledProcessError as ex:
        print(f"Failed to delete files. stdout: {ex.stdout}, stderr: {ex.stderr}, returncode: {ex.returncode}")
```

But you should change you while condition, you have an infinite loop there - (`while "temp"` will be always `True`)

Comment: but what do i set the condition to be?

Comment: whatever you want. If you're trying to delete the files one by one, you can replace the while loop with for loop and iterate over the files.

Answer (score 0):

The error is showed to you since you have a process that uses it(could be Command line interface or directly accessed by you)

However i find it the easiest to "skip" on files being used by another process with a try except block.

A try/except block will allow you to **handle** exceptions threw by builtin python commands you use  (like the one to delete a file).

More important, It wont crush your program during execution if you handle just with print something:

```py
try:
  #Run your deletion commands here
except:
  #Your code will run this block if there is an exception when your try to delete
  print('Something went wrong with that file you tried to delete.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while ("temp"):` should actually be equivalent to a `while True` loop since it will never stop.

You could utilize the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to accomplish your goal, e.g. (deleting the contents in `/tmp`)

```py
from pathlib import Path

for child in Path("/tmp").iterdir():
    if child.is_file():
        try:
            child.unlink()
        except Exception as Err:
            print(f"Error occured: {Err}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want a try/except statement.
and nest it in a for loop.

Your code will look like this:

```py
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    for file in files:
        path = os.path.join(dir, file)
        try:
            os.remove(path)
        except:
            pass
```

you use the os library's walk function to go through each of the files in "dir".
"dir" is the directory you want to delete from.
Then you loop through each of the files, and you try to delete it.

If you "try", and it fails, it skips over the file.